# How to stop cat command from outputting file name if it's piped to another command?

Tags: regular-expression, cat

I'm trying to learn regular expressions, and so I created a file with some characters in it. When I use the cat command and pipe it to rgrep command with an argument to filter out text, the resulting output is "filename:filtered_text".

```
cat regex.txt | rgrep -E '^a'
regex.txt:a
regex.txt:aa
regex.txt:aaa
regex.txt:aaaa
regex.txt:aaaaa
regex.txt:aaaaaa
file:acpi
file:adduser.conf
file:aliases
file:aliases.db
file:alternatives
file:anacrontab
file:apache2
file:apg.conf
file:apm
file:apparmor
file:apparmor.d
file:apport
file:appstream.conf
file:apt
file:avahi
```

Not only that it also checks for other files in the folder and if they match the regular expression it shows them as well, even though I only piped a single file.

How do I get a normal output with only the contents of the file I've passed into cat?

Comment: Can I ask what you are intending with the `-R` flag?

Comment: `cat` doesn't output the file names.

Comment: @BowlOfRed That was a mistake. I needed to use the -E option (for more options according to the video I'm watching). The output is still the same without any options.

Comment: Have you tried using `cat < regex.txt`?

Comment: @unxnut I did, just now, and got the same output. This time it even checked subdirectories.

Comment: OK, I see it now.  `rgrep` ignores the input from the pipe and instead, `grep`s all the files in your current directory recursively, giving you filenames.  The `cat` command on the left side of `|` is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-h` flag with `rgrep`, as it is the `rgrep` that prints the file names. This flags stops this.

I can only guess why you use `rgrep` as opposed to the simple `grep` and `cat`. So, first, you don't need `cat`. `grep PATTERN FILE` is enough. Second `rgrep` is equivalent to `grep -r`. And here's what the `-r` flag to `grep` does:

> **-r, --recursive**
>                 Read  all  files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  **Note
>   that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.**
>                 This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

For a simple solution, try:

```
grep '^a' regex.txt
```

(It's unclear with this pattern, why you would use the `-E` switch.)

Comment: That took out the file name but it still reads from all the files in the folder. I used '^a' and got lines starting with 'a' from all the files.

Comment: @Skaper Use normal `grep`

Comment: I used it but it gives me the whole output of the file with the characters matching the regular expression highlighted as red color. Shouldn't it only output the lines matching the regex?

Comment: @Skaper You need to ask a full question with what you do, what you expect and why, and what you get. I attempted a better answer with my edit.

Comment: @Skaper See a solution added.

Comment: That worked. I used rgrep because that's what is used in the video I watched (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHn9HMTG9Yc). When they use cat and pipe into rgrep there's no display of filename followed by ":". Maybe it has something to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Skaper I jumped over that video and don't see `rgrep` anywhere, only `egrep`, then `sed`. Strangely the guy uses `egrep -E`, while `egrep` itself is `grep -E`. This plus using `cat` in front in the pipeline means the video should be watched with caution.

Comment: WOW! I just saw the first part of the video once and didn't bother to look back. Used the wrong command. My bad :(

Answer (score -1):

`rgrep` is a shortcut (on my ubuntu 18.04: a script) for `grep -r`. `man grep`:

> ```
>    -r, --recursive
>           Read  all  files  under  each directory, recursively,
> ```

In fact, the use of `cat` is pointless, as `rgrep` seems to ignore it.

Comment: I'm using Linux 18.04.1 LTS. Are you talking about predefined aliases? If yes, then I don't have any for rgrep command.

Comment: No, it's a script in `/usr/bin`.